# Website fails to load in Safari Mobile and Desktop

Tags: apache, safari

When opening some web pages in Safari (iOS - CMS website hosted in a Apache server) it shows the following message.

[image]

1. Tried to remove all scripts from the page and it doesn't worked
2. Checked Apache access log and none on the requests were logged in access log
3. Checked Apache error log and no errors are logged

Tried lot of methods to figure it out (technically and logically). Anyone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

If none of your requests are being logged, then your client isn't getting through and you have a problem outside of your application scope (like a network connectivity or firewall issue)